# What happened to cowboy_http_handler in the Cowboy?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

Somebody tell me where is cowboy_http_handler in last version of Cowboy server?

Comment: It looks like there is code refactorization for version 2.0 which is not yet released. I think this behaviour is specified in `cowboy_handler.erl`. Not sure how it works now but maybe you should consider using version [1.0.1](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/tree/1.0.1) for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the information on github. here is a copy of the comment attached to cowboy_handler.erl:

> Improve handler interface and documentation
>
> This change simplifies a little more the sub protocols mechanism.
>   Aliases have been removed. The renaming of loop handlers as long
>   polling handlers has been reverted.
>
> Plain HTTP handlers now simply do their work in the init/2 callback.
>   There is no specific code for them.
>
> Loop handlers now follow the same return value as Websocket, they use
>   ok to continue and shutdown to stop.
>
> Terminate reasons for all handler types have been documented. The
>   terminate callback is now appropriately called in all cases (or should
>   be).
>
> Behaviors for all handler types have been moved in the module that
>   implement them. This means that cowboy_handler replaces the
>   cowboy_http_handler behavior, and similarly cowboy_loop replaces
>   cowboy_loop_handler, cowboy_websocket replaces
>   cowboy_websocket_handler. Finally cowboy_rest now has the start of a
>   behavior in it and will have the full list of optional callbacks
>   defined once Erlang 18.0 gets released.
>
> The guide has been reorganized and should be easier to follow.